# SQL Server - Is it possible to create an ascending identity based on a grouping of data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, identity

This is a tricky one so bear with me.

I have a table with 16000 rows, which has 3 unique indexes which are assigned by our application. So on a parent/child basis you would see something like this

```
Val1  Val2   client  sequence_no  sequence_ref
----------------------------------------------
A     AA     UK      1            1
A     AB     UK      2            1
A     AC     UK      3            1
B     BA     UK      1            2
B     BB     UK      2            2
C     CA     UK      1            3
C     CB     UK      2            3
C     CC     UK      3            3
C     CD     UK      4            3
```

The 3 right columns are the unique indexes. A user with too much access has loaded a number of rows that do not follow the logic, so I want to "cleanse" the data by extracting it into a temporary table, setting the sequences to 0 and updating them accordingly to the above.

I can do the `sequence_ref` easily by grouping by `Val1` and inserting an identity column and then updating the original table. However for `sequence_no` is proving more difficult, as I don't want the identity to continue running, I want it to start again at each new `Val1`.

Comment: what should be the output of sequence_no according to you ?

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate this data by using the `row_number` and `rank` window functions:

```
SELECT val1, val2, client
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY val1 ORDER BY sequence_ref) 
         AS good_sequence_no,
       RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY val1) 
         AS good_sequence_no
FROM   my_table
```

Comment: it will be desne_rank

Answer (score 1):

maybe this way?

```
sequence_no  = DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Val2)     
sequence_ref = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Val1 ORDER BY Val2)
```

Comment: Using them the other way round, so row number for sequence_no and dense_rank for sequence_ref. But that's done, thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Val1 ORDER BY sequence_no)
```